# Google analytics for iOS : why nothing happens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics

I implemented Google Analytics in my Android and iOS app. When I test the Android app, I can see it on analytics dashboard but it seems like my iOS app is not linked to Google Analytics.

My AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
    GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
    GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
    GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXX-1")
    return true
}
```

MyViewController.swift :

```
class MyViewController: GAITrackedViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.screenName = "myView"
    }
}
```

Google analytics logs when debugging my app :

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa

INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002

INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.12 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:368): No pending hits.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: link to `libAdIdAccess.a` library available in GoogleAnalytics framework, as well add `AdSupport.framework` into your project Frameworks

Comment: These libraries are optional and only useful for advertisers : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/
And I have no issue building the app.

Comment: as you are doing `automatic screen measurement` you require to link this library and framework. if you dont want to do so then disable `tracker.allowIDFACollection = NO`